# Error casting context.lookup(...) returned object to ejb3 remote object interface

Tags: java, jndi, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

I have an EJB stateless running under a JBoss server and a client under another JBoss server.

In the client side, I am using the following code:

```
final Properties initialContextProperties = new Properties();
initialContextProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
initialContextProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:8083");
initialContextProperties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
initialContextProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

final InitialContext contexte = new InitialContext(initialContextProperties);
Object remoteObj = contexte.lookup("ejb:my-web-app/MyEjbRemoteImpl!my.ejb.remote.MyEjbRemoteInterface");
MyEjbRemoteInterface myEjb = (my.ejb.remote.MyEjbRemoteInterface) remoteObj;
```

While running this code, I have this exception:

```
org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext cannot be cast to my.ejb.remote.MyEjbRemoteInterface
```

These dependencies are in the classpath of the client side:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
    <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Have you any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As stated on the section [Pre-requisites of remotely accessible JNDI objects](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project)  of JBoss's documentation, *the JNDI names used while using the remote-naming project are always relative to the **java:jboss/exported/** namespace*. Therefore, you should remove the `ejb:` from your lookup string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the lookup method string parameter. It must be like: `ejb:/my-web-app//MyEjbRemoteImpl!my.ejb.remote.MyEjbRemoteInterface`. Generally like `ejb:AppName/EjbModuleName/DistinctName/EjbRemoteBeanImpName!ejb.remote.interface.Name`

And all required dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```