# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext cannot be cast to

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ejb, wildfly

I have an EJB stateless project (helloworld) running under Wildfly 8.2.1 Final server with java 1.7 and a client app with java 1.8. I'm getting an error. Thank you

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext cannot be cast to
>   com.aburak.sb.SessionBeanRemote   at
>   com.aburak.sb.Driver.main(Driver.java:15)

this is my Driver Class which is Client Application

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
            Context context=Driver.getInitialContext();
            SessionBeanRemote sbRemote= (SessionBeanRemote) context.lookup("ejb:SessionBean/SessionBean!com.aburak.sb.SessionBeanRemote");
            sbRemote.sessionBeanMethod();
    }
    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8080");

        return new InitialContext(properties);
    }
}
```

Remote BeanSession

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class SessionBean implements  SessionBeanRemote, SessionBeanLocal{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7201692010023776738L;

@Override
public void sessionBeanMethod() {
    System.out.println("SessionBean executed...");

}
```

SessionBeanRemote

```
@Remote
public interface SessionBeanRemote extends SessionBeanIF{

}
```

(SessionBeanLocal is exact the same SessionBeanRemote except @Local annotation)

SessionBeanIF

```
public interface SessionBeanIF extends Serializable{
public void sessionBeanMethod();
}
```

and this is the client Drive class

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
            Context context=Driver.getInitialContext();
            SessionBeanRemote sbRemote= (SessionBeanRemote) context.lookup("ejb:SessionBean/SessionBean!com.aburak.sb.SessionBeanRemote");
            sbRemote.sessionBeanMethod();
    }
    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8080");

        return new InitialContext(properties);
    }
}
```

SessionBeanClient >> pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

SessionBean >> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I follow [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrDT-PYhG20) but i change something app server etc.
and also search the error find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219951/error-casting-context-lookup-returned-object-to-ejb3-remote-object-interfac) but it didn't solve my problem.

This is my [Package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWdu.png)

Thanks four your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your path for remote invocation is wrong. Take a look at full path at server log when you deploy the ejb to wildfly server.
It will look like

```
ejb:/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/SessionBean!com.thanhnn.training.SessionBeanRemote
```

You need a property file named 'jboss-ejb-client.properties' in resources folder of the client.

```
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connection.default.username=your-user-name
remote.connection.default.password=your-pass-word
```

To create an application user, run add-user.bat or add-user.sh in ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin and follow the process.

For the handshake process of client and server, you need the following dependencies in pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
        <artifactId>xnio-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
        <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.remoting</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.sasl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-sasl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And finally, the code for client

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    Context context=Driver.getInitialContext();
    SessionBeanRemote sbRemote= (SessionBeanRemote) context.lookup("ejb:/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/SessionBean!com.thanhnn.training.SessionBeanRemote");
    sbRemote.sessionBeanMethod();
}
public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    return new InitialContext(properties);
}
```

Note: you don't need to declare the method as public in the interface